# How would I explore maps in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I'm playing Overwatch and I want to gain a  better knowledge of the maps. I would like to explore the maps outside of a match, but can't find a game mode/tutorial, etc. that allows me to be in the map alone. Can anyone offer any advice?

Some youtubers have map tutorials where they freely fly around in maps with the camera without a hero. How do they do this? Is some third party software involved?

Comment: Although the other answer is perfectly fine and is exactly what you're looking for: I'd still recommend learning the maps by playing competitively (playing against real players). You might find all the small corners and back doors while by yourself but it's much better to play against real players and see where all the clash points are, where is most likely that the enemy will fight you and come from, which corners are more used by the enemy etc. By the end of the open beta I knew all the maps just by online play and knew all of them 80%+

Comment: I can agree with Иво that a good way to get used to the game/maps/heroes is to play competitively and learn it that way. Of course, if you don't want to play against people until you are "good," the "Play vs AI" option from the Play menu pits a team of 6 players against 6 bots, which are pretty easy enemies to deal with. You can learn good flanking paths and how abilities interact in this mode.

Comment: It depends. I see a lot of players not knowing alternate routes and in a real game you don't have the time to explore. Some routes are somewhat difficult and need practice. In some cases you need to try out what can and can't be done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **Custom Game** option in the Play menu. You can choose the map, the map rotation, the difficulty and amount of AI players, etc. This should allow you to play privately or with friends in order to increase your knowledge of maps and heroes.

http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Custom_Game

Edit: As to how the youtubers and others fly around the map, they use the custom game menu, and when viewing the team lineups page, they right click on their name and swap teams to the Spectator team. Then they start the match. This video shows how it can be done at around the 10:00 mark:

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this: select Custom Game, then add 1 Bot Zarya to each team (because Zarya's attack is weak and she has a shield so their fight will be 100% VERY TOUGH :)), and then I add myself to Spectators. In the settings of the game select 1-map mode. This is the way where you have most time to explore the map.